How far above a forest fire or conflagration would you need to be, to not burn alive?
I write fantasy. One of my main characters is kinda like a D&D druid with plantgrowth. He can magically will plants to grow with photosythesis.
He can for example get trees to grow really quickly, if there is sunlight, and some water and soil (with enough nutrients)
In one of the books there is a conflagration that he can't outrun. But he might be able to grow a mammouth tree / giant sequoia quick enough to get like 80 meters up into the air (And some flying creatures can get to him; "the eagles are coming!")
That tree would of course also catch fire, and the fire would "climb the tree" and reach him. But if he can get the tree to grow really tall, there might be enough time - but only IF the temperature from the fire below him doesn't kill him (he has a force-field thing with fresh air)
If you stand far away from a house fire, you don't feel the flames.
So the question is, how far above a conflagration would you need to be, to not get burned to a crisp in minutes?

Not entering into the mechanics of survival, but just a note that giant sequoias do not catch fire easily. In fact, they are adapted to forest fires, and forest fires are necessary for their reproduction. (The way it works is that the forest fire clears out all competing low-lying vegetation; the heat from the fire dries out the cones, so that the cones open and the seeds fall on the ground, which after the forest fire is clear of competing vegetation and full of nutrients.) Human efforts at avoiding forest fires is one of the major threats to the species.

80 meters above the leading edge of the fire would be toasty, but survivable. 80 meters above the active region of a forest fire might kill you - via smoke inhalation if not the heat, but that would be ugly, too. Whether or not a tree burns quickly has to do with moisture content and combustibility of the sap. In other words, you can write the story to rationalize the druid's survival. Note that hyperion redwoods top the scale at 116 meters. If the druid's tree isn't substantially above the others, the druid will cook.

Don’t go UP, go DOWN
Heat rises, and trees can dig down just as easily (if not as deeply) as they grow up. Especially since your Druid has a spell that breathes for him, have him use a tree to create an underground hollow, maybe 20 feet down or so, and shelter under the soil until the fire passes. Not only is this much more likely to work, it’s not dissimilar to how certain plants survive forest fires, so it’s thematically appropriate.

Watch out if conditions are very dry, though - it is possible for root systems or soil with lots of organic matter to burn even underground in certain cases.

@NuclearHoagie an incredibly intense forest fire might damage the soil 3-6 feet down. If you’re doing damage twenty feet down, that’s not a forest fire, that’s a low yield nuke.

@DanielB: That 3–6 feet you’re quoting is through solid soil.  If we’re talking a plausibly natural-seeming hollow formed by tree roots, accessible to the druid, and with reasonable ventilation (magical or natural), then it may well be survivable, but it certainly won’t be anywhere near as well-shielded as the same depth of solid soil.

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine He doesn't need ventilation, he has a "he has a force-field thing with fresh air". Absent that, I'd be much less optimistic about my theory. See the firebombing of Dresden, where the air got hot enough to kill people in underground shelters.

Fire emits hot gases which rise and carry heat. At a distance of 80 vertical meters, heat will spread mainly by convection of these gases, not by radiation or conduction. If the protagonist has a magical bubble of fresh air, they are not exposed to the hot gases from the fire - they won't get burned.
This won't be much different from standing next to a house fire, where heat is transmitted by radiation but not convection. Being above a fire is normally much hotter than being next to it because the gases rise, but this isn't an issue if you're inside a magical bubble of fresh air. The bubble will start to heat up due to the fact that it is surrounded by hot gases, but since air is a very good thermal insulator, it will take some time before the bubble itself heats up to dangerous levels.

The radiation works just as well at 80 meters, though. For that, it mostly matters how much of the field of view is radiating towards you, not so much how far away.

Maybe the druid can get the tree to grow a thick, solid heat shield below him to buy more time.

@PaŭloEbermann The radiation "works just as well", yes, but that's still not very well at all. Which is good, because otherwise forest fires would propagate at the speed of light. Lava is much hotter than forest fires, yet even in vast quantities it can't even wither foliage via radiant transfer alone.

This paper talks about real-world helicopters for fire-fighting (i.e. by dropping buckets of water).
You might like to read the text yourself, it is quite fascinating. One paragraph says:

Therefore, when flying over such areas, the limitations of maximum ambient air temperature limits must be taken into account. For example, using the methodology set out in 1 for high intensity fires (20000 kW/m) with diameter of 15 m, the following values of the ambient air temperature are observed at altitude H: 190°C at H = 30 m; 110°C at H = 50 m; 15°C at H = 100 m. Therefore, helicopter flight at an altitude of 30-70 m is dangerous because of the possibility of engine surge.

So, real-world helis are at danger at 30-70m; not only because of the temperature itself but also because motors could stop working due to hot air in the intake, and because of very significant air turbulence. This could give you a hint for your character. You mentioned that your tree can grow to 80m quickly, this would be sufficient for survival, together with your magical air bubble, while still not being fun at all.
For how quickly your tree burns up itself, this would be mostly up to you as a story device. In the real world, this kind of speed can vary greatly depending on the dryness of the medium (wood). Famously, in accidents where real wax candles were used on Christmas trees, a living room could turn into a flaming hell within literal seconds (not only from the tree itself burning, but also other extremely dry materials like wallpapers or curtains or wood paneling at the ceiling). If your druid is top notch, he can use his magic to instruct the tree to pull as much water as possible into its capillaries or leaves, to give him more time.


If you stand far away from a house fire, you don't feel the flames.

Heat rises, if you were over the burning house you'd be cooked because the heat is going straight up.
A forest fire is the same except a lot bigger. You would need to be 100 metres or more higher than the fire and still would not have much time. Once the fire is directly beneath and around you, no tree height will save you. It would be a race between cooking and asphyxiating.
But if you could get 80 metres up before the fire reaches you, and then get picked up by a magical bird you'd be fine I would think.

There are three kinds of heat transfer:

Radiant heat - This is infrared light, so it travels in a straight line.
Convection - This is from air currents (hot air rises).
Conduction - This occurs when touching something hot.

It seems easy for your character to avoid all 3 types of heat for a time:

Grow several large trees to act as a shield - this blocks the radiant heat.
Use the "force-field thing with fresh air" - presumably, this will block the heat from convection currents.
Make sure that he isn't touching anything that is actually on fire.

A likely candidate would be a tall redwood tree, as the 30 cm (1 foot) thick bark filled with tannin acid and water protects the tree from damage during fires.
https://sempervirens.org/news/redwoods-and-wildfires/
Giant sequoia trees and several other varieties are also fire-resistant.
https://www.arborday.org/perspectives/are-some-trees-fire-resistant-actually-yes
For a more extreme example, check out the Parker Space Probe that is equipped with a carbon heat shield that allows it to travel very close to the sun without burning up.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parker_Solar_Probe#Spacecraft
